# Runnable jar not reflecting change in db file

Tags: java, sql, jar, applet

I have a runnable jar that populates a JComboBox with the results from an SQL command to an SQLite database.  I have since changed some spelling errors in the database and recompiled the .jar but the errors persist.  To test that I was editing the right file in the right path, I changed the filename do db2.db, and the runnable crashed. (file not found).
I check the table with SQLite Viewer and the changes are there, so I rename it back to db.db, recompile and run and the spelling errors are back!

What's going on?

**Edit1: more info:**
Tested on OS X and Windows. People who DL a fresh jar see updated changes, just not people who have had an old version. Also, one person ran jetclean and it worked. Simply clearing java cache does not work.

**Edit2:**  When I run it in eclipse, everything is fine.  This only happens when I run it as a runnable.jar on machines that have had older versions of the same program run perviously.  Machines that have not had the old version (containing the old db) run on them are not affected.

**Edit3**  Some have suggested not putting the db inside the .jar  While I agree that this would work, I want to know why this is happening and actually learn something instead of hacking around the problem.

Comment: Well, if your statement is correct, it will retrieve the data at the moment you run the query, no matter if you compile the jar again or not. The only thing I can think of is that the changes you made in the database are only in your session and not yet visible to the outside, is that possible?

Comment: No, because I save the file, close the viewer, open it and the changes are there, but when I recompile the db and run the jar it's like the db was never changed.
Tested on OS X and Windows.
People who DL a fresh jar see updated changes, just not people who have had an old version.
Also, one person ran jetclean and it worked.  Simply clearing java cache does not work.

Comment: Does the runnable JAR (re-)generate the database from scratch?

Comment: It does not, the .jar contains the db. The db is edited and then repackaged with the jar.